# Angular 8 - Unit test for abstract service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, abstract-class

I should write a unit test for an abstract service. We have couple of SSE channels in the application and we created base SSE service to be extended and it provides some basic functionality.

```
export abstract class BaseSseService {
  protected zone: NgZone;

  protected sseChannelUrl: string;

  private eventSource: EventSource;
  private reconnectFrequencySec: number = 1;
  private reconnectTimeout: any;

  constructor(channelUrl: string) {
    const injector = AppInjector.getInjector();
    this.zone = injector.get(NgZone);
    this.sseChannelUrl = channelUrl;
  }

  protected abstract openSseChannel(): void;
  //...
}
```

Now, before it was made abstract unit test were running. Once I changed it to the abstract class, I'm getting this error while trying to run `should be created` test: `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TestBaseSseService: (?).`

My test looks like this:

```
class TestBaseSseService extends BaseSseService {
  openSseChannel() {
    console.log('Test');
  }
}

fdescribe('BaseSseService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestBaseSseService,
        Injector,
        { provide: String, useValue: "test" }
      ]
    });
    AppInjector.setInjector(TestBed.get(Injector));
  })

  describe(':', () => {
    function setup() {
      return TestBed.get(TestBaseSseService)
    }

    it('should be created', () => {
      const service = setup();
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });  
});
```

The question is, should I even bother with unit test for abstract service and if so how to solve this issue? As you can see, mocking the service does not solve this nor does adding `BaseSseService` to `TestBed` providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to provide the `channelUrl` from the abstract class, but this is obviously not a provider or an InjectionToken.

You can change your service to handle this:

```
class TestBaseSseService extends BaseSseService {
  constructor() {
    super('url');
  }

  openSseChannel() {
    console.log('Test');
  }
}
```

And yes, it's always good to test an abstract class. This way you can be sure-ish that whenever you implement it, it will act the same (when tested properly)

Comment: This solved the issue. And it's no longer necessary to provide `channerlUrl` in TestBed providers. Thanks.